# Displaying a flash message using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to have some sort of a pop up screen or flash message using Laravel, currently I have set up a route and which is triggerd using Ajax call, which is submitting a field to a Controller method to verify if a certain user has any violations, when clicking the button "check for violation" nothing is happening and I am not getting any flash messages in my page.
here is my view:

```xml
@if(Session::has('success'))
  <script type="text/javascript">
     swal({
         title:'Info!',
         text:"{{Session::get('success')}}",
         timer:5000,
         type:'info'
     }).then((value) => {
       location.reload();
     }).catch(swal.noop);
 </script>
 @endif
<form action="{{ route('assignees.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="POST">
    @csrf

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Customer ID:</strong>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="custidno" id='cust' required autocomplete="off" onkeypress="myFunction()"  placeholder="Customer ID" >
                <button onclick="CheckViolation()"class="btn-info"type="button">Check for Violation</button>
                </div>
              </div>
```

JS Code

```xml
function CheckViolation()
  {
    var customerid= document.getElementById("cust").value;
    var url = "{{ url('violationcheck') }}";
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", url + "?" +"custidno=" + customerid, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

and that's my route:

```php
Route::get('violationcheck', 'ViolationController@violationcheck')->name('violationcheck');
```

and that's my basic controller method

```php
public function violationcheck(Request $request)
{

  $custidno = customer::select("id")
  ->where('name',$request->custidno)
  ->first();
  $checked = DB::table('violations')
  ->select('severity',DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
  ->where("customer_id",$custidno->id)
  ->where("status",1)
  ->groupBy('severity')
  ->first();
  if(empty($checked))
  {
    $msg="No Violation found";
  }else{
      $msg="Violation found";

        }
        return redirect()->route('assignees.create')->with("success",$msg);

  }
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your route is get but the form is set to post try ` Route::post('violationcheck', 'ViolationController@violationcheck')->name('violationcheck');
`
EDIT On closer inspection I can see you have another open for that it is nested in. You cannot nest forms

Comment: change `@if ($message = Session::get('info'))` to `@if (Session::has('info'))`. ** Why do you have nested form?

Comment: First of all, you've got a form inside another form. Why? Also, you won't get your 'info' with Session::get(), try @isset($info) @endisset instead

Comment: I have removed the nested forms and used Ajax call instead, I am unable to get the flash message to display in the page now.

Comment: @Abdul What Laravel version do you use?

Comment: @konstantinkoslowi am on 5.8

Comment: @Clint I have changed it to an Ajax call but I am unable to display the flash message now.. the controller method is being executed but return value is not displaying flash message on the screen

Comment: Because you have made the request over ajax the alert won't render. The check for if the alert exists is blade so php. You can return the result as json and then in your js CheckViolation() use the response result to update the page.

Comment: @Abdul I can see you have change to swal js alerts. This doesn't resolve the issue because the if is still server side so the code for the alert doesn't make it to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```php
@if (session('info'))
    <div class="alert alert-info">
        {{ session('info') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Read more about [Redirecting With Flashed Session Data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data)

Comment: I have tried it, the message is not being displayed, clicking at the button will trigger the controller but no flash msg

Comment: @Abdul i think that's because now you return success instead of info